# Editable table in meteor

Tags: meteor, datatable

I wish to create an editable table in meteor.

I have gone through the following links:

[reactive table](https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table) and
[autoform](http://autoform.meteor.com/)

but not able to get anywhere, Am I looking in the right place?Please guide.I am new to meteor, any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at meteor-editable (https://github.com/davidworkman9/meteor-editable)?

Comment: => Errors while parsing arguments:           
                                              
While adding package meteor-editable:
error: no such package

Comment: Use: meteor add workman:meteor-editable

Comment: but how to use it, there are no examples

Comment: This is not able to update the DB..only working at the UI level

Comment: How about the example table shown here?: http://autoform.meteor.com/update-each

Comment: How to edit the table itself, here it is editing one row at a time

Answer (score 2):

I simply make an editable table using pure js and style it by bootstrap, Semantic UI or whatever you want.
The following is my table row template

```
<template name="item">
  {{#if editing}}
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="editItemStore" value="{{store}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="editItemName" value="{{name}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="editItemWeight" value="{{weight}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="editItemWeightType" value="{{weightType}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="editItemQty" value="{{qty}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="editItemQtyType" value="{{qtyType}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="editItemPrice" value="{{price}}"></td>
      <td><button class="saveItem">save</button><button class="cancelItem">Cancel</button>{{#each errors}}<div>{{message}}</div>{{/each}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{else}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{store}}</td>
      <td>{{name}}</td>
      <td>{{weight}}</td>
      <td>{{weightType}}</td>
      <td>{{qty}}</td>
      <td>{{qtyType}}</td>
      <td>{{price}}</td>
      <td><button class="editItem">Edit</button><button class="deleteItem">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

and the following is my row template events handler

```
Template.item.helpers({
  editing: function(){
    return Session.equals('editItemId', this._id);
  } 
});

Template.item.events({
  'click .deleteItem': function(){
    Items.remove(this._id);
  },
  'click .editItem': function(){
    Session.set('editItemId', this._id);
  },
  'click .cancelItem': function(){
    Session.set('editItemId', null);
  },
  'click .saveItem': function(){
    saveItem();
  },
  'keypress input': function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
      saveItem();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === 27){
      Session.set('editItemId', null);
    }
  }
});
var saveItem = function(){
  var editItem = {
    store: $("#editItemStore").val(),
    name: $("#editItemName").val(),
    weight: $("#editItemWeight").val(),
    weightType: $("#editItemWeightType").val(),
    qty: $("#editItemQty").val(),
    qtyType: $("#editItemQtyType").val(),
    price: $("#editItemPrice").val()
  }

  Items.update(Session.get('editItemId'), {$set: editItem});
  Session.set('editItemId', null);
}
```

please refer to this [Complete Tutorial](http://douglashirsh.com/2015/02/06/meteor-js-part-4-editing-input-validation/)

Answer (score 1):

I use `meteor add olragon:handsontable`

It works well. Check out the [tutorials](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.0/demo-jquery.html) and [docs](http://handsontable.com/).

> Handsontable is a data grid component with an Excel-like appearance.
>   Built in JavaScript, it integrates with any data source with peak
>   efficiency. It comes with powerful features like data validation,
>   sorting, grouping, data binding, formula support or column ordering.
>   Built and actively supported by the Handsoncode team and the GitHub
>   community , distributed free under the MIT license.

Comment: @D'loDeProjuicer - no, I haven't. If you get a chance to do so, we'd love to know your thoughts on it!